# Log4j2: different files according to called logger method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, log4j2

Following [officiale Apache guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), I managed to write this silly xml file to configure my loggers with log4j2 2.10:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="FileFatal" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/fatal.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
     <File name="FileError" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/error.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
     <File name="FileWarn" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/warn.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
     <File name="FileInfo" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/info.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
     <File name="FileDebug" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/debug.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
     <File name="FileTrace" immediateFlush="true" fileName="bin/logs/trace.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileFatal" level="fatal"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileError" level="error"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileWarn" level="warn"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileInfo" level="info"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileDebug" level="debug"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileTrace" level="trace"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

which seems to work fine.
Anyway, I would like that `error()`, `info()`, `debug()`, `warn()`, `trace()` methods to be written in different specific files, beside console obviously. Instead, for example, inside warn log file I also find error and fatal ones. How shall I set up it? That does not seem a standard xml configuration like I've found anywhere else, there are some different tags with different syntax.

Comment: Turn additivity off. See [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity).

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. I've put  `additivity="false" ` in Root tag but it doesn't work.